# Injection of autowired dependencies failed for QueueChannel

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring-batch application that processes a bunch of files, then archives them (moves them in another folder) as the last step of the job.

The job archiving step is configured like this :

```
<batch:job id="cdsTradesLoadJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    ...
    <batch:step id="stepCdsArchives">
        <batch:tasklet ref="cdsArchivesTasklet"/>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<beans:bean id="cdsArchivesTasklet"
    class="c.h.i.c.b.c.t.CdsArchivesTasklet" scope="step">
    <beans:property name="resource" value="file://${cds.archive.file.path}" />
</beans:bean>
```

The `Tasklet` looks like this :

```
public class CdsArchivesTasklet implements Tasklet {
    private Resource resource;
    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Autowired
    QueueChannel archiveCdsChannel;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext arg1) throws Exception {
        // processing...
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Finally, the channel used in the Tasklet is defined in a `integration-file-outbound-cds.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:batch-int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration"
    xmlns:batch-integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration/spring-batch-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd">

    <channel id="archiveCdsChannel" >
        <int:queue/>
    </channel>

    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="archiveCds" channel="archiveCdsChannel" directory="${cds.archive.file.path}"
        delete-source-files="true" auto-create-directory="true">
        <poller fixed-delay="5000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
    </int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>
</beans:beans>
```

When all this is set, the last step (archiving) of the job fails, because spring could not autowire the `archiveCdsChannel` field.

In the logs, it appears that the xml file containing the definition of the channel is found and loaded... What am I missing here ?

The exception raised here :

```
2019-05-27 12:07:04,982 INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [cpm-integration-file-outbound-cds.xml]
...
2019-05-27 12:07:16,373 INFO [main] o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter [IntegrationMBeanExporter.java:779] Registering MessageChannel archiveCdsChannel
2019-05-27 12:07:16,373 INFO [main] o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter [MBeanExporter.java:674] Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=archiveCdsChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=archiveCdsChannel]
...
2019-05-27 12:07:21,358 ERROR [main] o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep [AbstractStep.java:229] Encountered an error executing step stepCdsArchives in job cdsTradesLoadJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.CdsArchivesTasklet': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel c.h.i.c.b.c.t.CdsArchivesTasklet.archiveCdsChannel; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:344) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:339) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy60.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy26.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:362) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:592) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel c.h.i.c.b.c.t.CdsArchivesTasklet.archiveCdsChannel; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Use `MessageChannel` (the super interface) instead of the concrete implementation `QueueChannel`.

Comment: Why did that work ?

Comment: There probably is a proxy being created which acts as the interfaces implemented by the class. `MessageChannel` is the most generic interface for channels available.